# Win7 create generic credentials from a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, credentials

I'm trying to create a batch file that will create Generic credentials in WIN7. I have come up with the following code but I'm not seeing any new entries. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
cmdkey /generic:computername /user:domain\userName /pass: Password
```

Comment: Are running the script as an Administrator **and** elevating the permissions of the process?

Comment: You are running this on the DC I assume?  You don't assign any user groups...that also isn't how you add a domain user....

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do? It looks like you might be using a command for something it doesn't do.

Comment: The Generic credentials are to allow an RDP shortcut to have the credentials saved to the shortcut. So the user doesn't have to enter the remote PC user name and password.                                                  
                                                                                                              
[link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/manage-network-logon-credentials-in-microsoft-windows/#<h2>Adding/Editing credentials</h2>)

Comment: After looking at my code with fresh eyes the next day I realized I had space between "/ pass: Password", when it should have been "/pass: Password".

Answer (score 1):

After looking at my code with fresh eyes the next day I realized I had space between / pass

```
"/ pass: Password"
```

when it should have been

```
"/pass: Password".
```

The script works but, I'm confused to why it did create the generic credentials without a password.

Answer (score -3):

cmdkey /add:computer /user:administrator /pass:password

Comment: This is exactly what OP put in their question. If you're trying to answer the question you'll need to give more info. If you're just posting, please read the Help section to learn more about this site and how it works.